# PostgreSQL backup restore

Tags: postgresql, gis

I am using Postgresql 9.5.10 for developing vehicle tracking application and taking daily backups as pg_dump Custom format.  But while restoring the same it shows.

```
$ pg_restore -h localhost -d dbname -U user  -a tracking_data.sql
pg_restore: [compress_io] could not uncompress data: (null)
```

Comment: That error sounds to me like the end of file is reached while it is expecting more data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `psql` to restore plain SQL (like in your example) script file generated by  `pg_dump` and  `pg_dumpall` tools.

```
psql -U username --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f backupfile.sql
```

The command above is restoring a database and stops if error occurs.

`pg_restore` is used to restore tar file and directory format created by the  `pg_dump` tool.